# How can i use a defined AS alias in WHERE section of my query?

Tags: mysql

Why doesnt the following query work?

```
    SELECT uid, 
       CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) AS name,
       (SELECT COUNT(t1.id) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.reference = user_id) AS amount  
     FROM users 
        WHERE type = 'SLA' AND amount > 0;
```

In my SELECT portion of the query i use the AS alias. Which works fine but now i want to ensure that the ALIASES actually hold some value and only return the rows of those that does so.

I am missing something i guess?

Comment: You cannot use aliasses in where clause.

Comment: any idea how to accomplish this then?

Comment: The inner `SELECT` statement looks weird since it has no reference to the outer `SELECT` statement. Are you sure you are using the correct sub select statement? Or do you want to use a `JOIN` instead?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: With the `COUNT()` expression added, you will now get always a result, even if that mean that you might get `0` as count. Please edit your question to include the table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements), sample input for these tables and the expected result. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for how to ask SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias name in `where` from `select` clause, I guess you can write a `JOIN` subquery get another result set to instead of it.

```
SELECT u.uid,
     CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) AS name,
     t1.amount 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as amount,
           reference
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY reference
) t1 ON t1.reference = u.user_id
WHERE u.type = 'SLA' and t1.amount > 0
```